# TypeError: deviceToken.data is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase

i am trying to create a push notification with firebase function but i keep getting

> TypeError: deviceToken.data is not a function

here is my code

```
 exports.likeFunction = functions.firestore.document("Likes/{meId}/userLikes/{UserLikeId}").onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        if (!snapshot.exists) {
            console.log('No Device');
        }
        var tokens = [];
        var UserLikeId = context.params.UserLikeId;
    
        const deviceToken = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(UserLikeId).get();
        for (var token in deviceToken) {
            tokens.push(token.data().tokens)
        }
        try {
            await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
                tokens,
                {
                    data: {
                        owner: JSON.stringify("Like"),
                        user: JSON.stringify(deviceToken.data().name + ' Like You'),
                    },
                },
                {
    
                    contentAvailable: true,
    
                    priority: "high",
                }
            );
            console.log("Firebase Messaging Successfully");
        } catch (err) {

        console.log("error from messaging " + err);
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting await where you set deviceToken i.e.

`const deviceToken = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(UserLikeId).get();`

(I'm not 100% sure but..) I suspect this line is async and the promise hasn't resolved by the time you try to reference the deviceToken later on